# Why can i not find MSBuild in multi solution asp.net-core application within a docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to contain my asp.net-core application into a docker container. As I use the Microsoft-secret-store for saving credentials, I need to run a dotnet user-secrets command withing my container. The application needs to read these credentials when starting, so I have to run the command prior to starting my application. When trying to do that in my Dockerfile I get the error:

```
 ---> Running in 90f974a06d83
Could not find a MSBuild project file in '/app'. Specify which project to use with the --project option.
```

I tried building my application first and then building a container with the already build dll, but that gave me the same error. I also tried connecting to the container with ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"] and then looking around in the container. It seems that the /app folder that gets created does not have the .csproj files included. Im not sure if that could be an error.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Joinme.Facade/Joinme.Facade.csproj", "Joinme.Facade/"]
COPY ["Joinme.Domain/Joinme.Domain.csproj", "Joinme.Domain/"]
COPY ["Joinme.Business/Joinme.Business.csproj", "Joinme.Business/"]
COPY ["Joinme.Persistence/Joinme.Persistence.csproj", "Joinme.Persistence/"]
COPY ["Joinme.Integration/Joinme.Integration.csproj", "Joinme.Integration/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Joinme.Facade/Joinme.Facade.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Joinme.Facade"
RUN dotnet build "Joinme.Facade.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Joinme.Facade.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
RUN dotnet user-secrets set "jwt:secret" "some_password"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Joinme.Facade.dll"]
```

My expected results are that the secret gets set, so I can start the container without it crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain and simple: the operation is failing because at this stage, there is no `*.csproj` file(s), which the `user-secrets` command requires. However, this is not what you should be doing anyways for a few reasons:

1. User secrets are not for production. You can just as easily, or in fact *more* easily, set an environment variable here instead, which doesn't require `dotnet` or the SDK.

   ```
   ENV jwt:secret some_password
   ```
2. You should not actually be storing secrets in your Dockerfile, as that goes into your source control, and is exposed as plain text. Use [Docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/), or an external provider like Azure Key Vault.
3. You don't want to build your final image based on the SDK, anyways. That's going to make your container image *huge*, which means both longer transfer times to/from the container registry and higher storage/bandwidth costs. Your final image should be based on the runtime, or even something like alpine, if you publish self-contained (i.e. keep it as small as possible).